# How to disregard --user installed libs?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I develop in a cloud platform environment based on AWS instances (linux) in python.

In this platform we deal with python dependencies this way :

- A set of libs are installed when we deploy the plateform with a `pip install libname`command
- If a specific user wants to install a custom lib its installation is rolled back as a `pip install --user libname`

We also provide applications (notebooks) and to avoid conflicts I would like these notebook to only use the system installed libs is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, ensure the [`PYTHONNOUSERSITE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE) env var is set and you should be good to go.

Comment: Is it possible to use this this env variable (or the -s Python option) when I start a notebook ? 
I tried to do it in the first cell but it's to late sys.path is already loaded

Comment: You mean `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 jupyter notebook`? Or run `export PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1`, then `jupyter notebook`.

Comment: I mean that I have no control over the jupyter command (it's a btn in the plateform) i can just do things after in the jupyter cells

Comment: `sys.path.remove(site.USER_SITE)` would also do, although clumsy